# Ant PropertyRegex won't support var substitution dynamically on the attribute "input"

Tags: ant, target

I created an ant target that uses PropertyRegex to process strings, I defined the PropertyRegex as follows, the "input" field was wished to recieve a var substitution ,

```
<propertyregex property="getGroupOfTask"
    input="${taskid}"    <!-- @FFFF -->
    regexp="^([^\s]+)(?==)"
    select="\1"
/>
```

The target definition was as follows

```
<target name="xxx">
     <for param=line list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
         <sequential>
             <var name="taskid" vaule="@{line}">
             <echo>the taskid is ${getGroupOfTask}</echo>   <!-- @TTTT -->
         </sequential>
     </for>
</target>
```

when I ran this target and loaded the file,tasks could be printed correctly ( at the palce @TTTT),but input field (@FFFF) could't receive the content, why? What should I do ?

Comment: Could you describe what you're trying to accomplish here at a higher level? It's usually not necessary, and even potentially dangerous/problematic, to rely on loops and property overwriting in Ant.